# How do I access the data store once while creating a reference property?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Django with Google App Engine. At some point, I create two objects. One of the objects is a reference property of another. Currently, I am doing

```
b = models.B()
b.put()
a.reference = b
a.put()
```

Ideally, I'd like to just use `db.put([a, b])`, but object `b` lacks a key at the time I assign it to a property of object `a`.

Can I somehow give object `b` a key before actually putting it into the data store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom key like `B(key=ndb.Key(B, 'custom_key'))` so then you can reference this property even if it is do not exists yet.

If you would like to have a numeric key use `custom_key = B.allocate_ids(1)` first.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#numeric_keys

**EDIT:**

For db you need something like this: (not tested though)

```
start_batch, end_batch = db.allocate_ids(db.Key.from_path('B', 1), 1)
assert start_batch == end_batch
b = models.B(key_name=start_batch)
a.reference = db.Key.from_path('B', start_batch)
db.put([a, b])
```